# AWS Elastic Load Balancer vs. Elastic Beanstalk network bytes in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to figure out what is causing occasional spikes in the NetworkIn reported by my Elastic Beanstalk (EB) instances. I reviewed the monitoring graphs for EB by summing the NetworkIn bytes at 5 minute intervals and see peaks of 191MB. I want to find out where that specific traffic is coming from so I configured my Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) for that particular EB to send the logs to S3. I loaded the S3 logs into Splunk and can't see NetworkIn bytes anywhere near the number reported by EB, again by summing over 5 minute intervals.

Is there an explanation as to why the logs from ELB are not telling the same story as the EB monitoring graphs?

Comment: How much difference are you seeing? Also since ec2 instances behind  EBS are managed by the service, so you may need help from aws support to identify what all is going on in the instance

Comment: The difference is quite large. At one point on the graph it's showing 191MB for a 5 minute window. The ELB logs show less than 10MB for that same window.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and after those peaks the instance is killed and relaunched. Since I'm running min 1 instance, this is causing application to be down for a couple of minutes. Did you then find out what caused it?